# SOLVED - Rotating objects along curve direction with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

For the life of me I can't figure out how to **work out the rotation for the supports for this highway.** (No rotation attempt in the tree right now, I cleaned it up)

The base object is just **vertexes that are converted into a curve**. All that works just fine.

I'm also happy with how many supports are there. What I'm not happy with is the fact that I can't figure out how the rotation is supposed to be done. I tried normals, tangents, what have you, and I know the solution is out there somewhere, but I can't figure it out to save my life.

Comment: looks like it just might, but I was already provided an answer, thanks !

Comment: Yes, I see that, I'm just trying to avoid duplicates of repetitive questions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Align euler to vector is the "magic" node here.

Comment: Yeah this is the answer. Thank you a lot ! So thankful.

Comment: please click on the checkmark left of my answer if it helped you. thanks

Comment: absolutely, done now. I would have upvoted but I created this account for this question and so I can't yet...

Comment: No problem. Don’t need to be upvotes 